# Trying C# parse Json into Dictionary with inner arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, json, dictionary, collections

I am new in C# please clarify how to parse this JSON. I need to iterate over inner arrays to extract some data.
JSON:

```
{
    "p": [{
        "p": [{
            "p": "Get in ",
            "f": [],
            "t": "t"
        },
        {
            "p": "test",
            "t": "lb",
            "id": "Make"
        },
        ....
```

for example need access to dictionary "{"p": "Get in ", "f": [], "t": "t"}"
Do the following:

```
Dictionary<string, object> result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(bodyString);
List<Dictionary<string, object>> itemsArray = result["p"] as List<Dictionary<string, object>>;

foreach(var itemInfo in itemsArray)
{

}
```

But itemsArray is null.

Comment: What about your "result" dictionary, is that one filled?

Comment: Yes filled with data.

Comment: First of all, look at which keys are present in your dictionary.
Seconds, try this:
result["p"] is List<Dictionary<string, object>>;
This results in a bool, telling you whether or not this actually is a list

Comment: Use a debugger and observe what is the real type of result["p"]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you create a model to fit the data, then you won't have to worry about issues with multiple levels of dictionary deserialization.

```
void Main()
{
    var json = @"{
   ""p"":[
      {
         ""p"":[
            {
               ""p"":""Get in "",
               ""f"":[

               ],
               ""t"":""t""
            },
            {
               ""p"":""test"",
               ""t"":""lb"",
               ""id"":""Make""
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}";

    var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ItemCollection>(json);
}

public class ItemCollection
{
    public ItemGroup[] p { get; set; }
}

public class ItemGroup
{
    public Item[] p { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public string p { get; set; }
    public string t { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string[] f { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you deserialize as a dictionary of string to object, the objects will be JArray, Jobject or JToken.
            {
                var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject>(json);

```
            Console.WriteLine((result["p"]).GetType().Name);
        }
```

Will output 'JArray'.

You could work with JArray and so on, or specify the full structure you want:

```
        {
            var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, List<Dictionary<string,List<Dictionary<string,object>>>>>>(json);

            Console.Write((result["p"]).GetType().Name);
            var itemsArray = result["p"];
            var item = result["p"][0]["p"][0];

            foreach(var entry in item)
                Console.WriteLine(entry.Key + " = " + entry.Value);
        }
```